# Don't get info from db with spring jpa

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to get data from Oracle.

I have `@OneToMany` relation in class *"Home"*

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "obj_id", referencedColumnName = "obj_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private List<Room> roomCollection;
```

I have this repository:

```
    @Repository
    public interface FkvaRepository extends JpaRepository<ROOM, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM ROOM WHERE OBJ_ID=?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ROOM> findAllByObjectId(Long id);
}
```

I have a controller which get all rooms by home id:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/room/{id}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public List<Room> getRoom(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id) {

        List<Room> roomCollection = roomRepository.findAllByObjectId(id);
        return roomCollection;
    }
```

But when I tried

```
http://localhost:9000/room/466
```

I have the correct count of room objects in the result, but all of them are duplicate of the first.

How could I fix it?

Comment: Please put the actual code, in the current one there is a `Room` class and a `ROOM` class . Also consider adding the code of `Room` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SELECT * FROM ROOM WHERE OBJ_ID=?1 is the issue here.

Use following

```
List<ROOM> findAllByRoomId(Long id);
```

Where Id is room's entity primary id. remove native query code.

Comment: yes, for table where were shown duplicates i must add id primary key value.